# how to avoid column in 'where' clause if parameter is 'NOT PASSED' postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, where-clause

Running Query :

`select * from employee where name = $1 and age = $2 and salary =  $3;`

Problem Query :

`select * from employee where name = $1 and age = $2;`

**How can I write A Logic That**
/* If $3 is PASSED Then (`and salary =  $3` ) */

**Note** : 
/* I Cannot **check** For **null** or **Empty** as **$3** as not passed then **$3** won't be available for **check***/

*In Node I Am using Like This*

```
        postGresAdaptor.executeQueryWithParameters(QUERY, QUERYPARAMS, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {                    
                data = result.data;                    
            }
        });
```

Don't Want To Add Logic in node code as there will be lots of queries on the way.

Comment: *Passed* from where?

Comment: @Eggplant i haved edited question title it is 'passed in'

Comment: Ok, *who* or *what* passes is those parameters? Is this query part of a PL/pgSQL function? Or is it executed from some programming language?

Comment: @Eggplant : 1: there is field on ui and user might or might not use that field and so if he dosent uses that field i want that to be avoided in where clause   2: it is exectued from programming language node

Comment: Your are quite cryptic, but we are arriving to the point little by little... The next step is to know *how do you pass those parameters* or, better, please show the code you are using to execute that query passing the parameters.

Comment: one thing to note if i do not pass parameter $3 from user side $3 is used in query then it gives obvious error '2 parameters passed but prepared statement requires 3'

Comment: The only reasonable thing to do is changing the query like *wildplasser* wrote in his answer and deal with the optional parameter in node, ie: initializing to `null` the variables used to bind the parameters... It is something you have to fix in your programming language, not in SQL.

Comment: What is `node`, an ORM thing? (in that case: add it to the tags)

Comment: @wildplasser In [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) I am Not using ORM .I am simply using (postgresql adapter  code) to get data.

Comment: How should we know? Now I spent 15 minutes answering a different question!

Comment: @wildplasser : i Tried to make that question simple.Except the node part i added very late as Eggplant drilled the question and i modified and answered also i din't figured that the tree would grow in this many branches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not very clear what you mean by *is passed*, but maybe you mean that `$3` is an optional parameter, with `$3` absent meaning: *don't care* ?

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE name = $1
AND age = $2
AND ( $3 IS NULL OR salary = $3)
   ;
```

---

Some data:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
        ( name varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , age integer
        , salary integer
        );

INSERT INTO employee ( name , age , salary ) VALUES
 ( 'Alice' , 13 , 3 )
,( 'Bob' , 11 , 5 )
,( 'Charlotte' , 15 , 9 )
,( 'David' , 17 , 10 )
        ;
```

---

The same as a prepared query:

```
PREPARE qry (text, integer , integer) AS
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE name = $1
AND age = $2
AND ( $3 IS NULL OR salary = $3)
   ;

    -- and call the prepared statement:
EXECUTE qry ('Alice', 13, 3);
EXECUTE qry ('Alice', 13, NULL);
```

---

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
PREPARE
 name  | age | salary 
-------+-----+--------
 Alice |  13 |      3
(1 row)

 name  | age | salary 
-------+-----+--------
 Alice |  13 |      3
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html) argument type something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _my_function(_name character varying, _age integer, _salary integer default NULL)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
    begin

    if (_salary IS NULL) then

       select * from employee where name = _name and age = _age ;
    else
       select * from employee where name = _name and age = _age and salary =  _salary;
    end IF;
        return 'OK';

end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```