# Postgres: Function with optional “WHERE” parameters

Tags: postgresql, function, graphql, plpgsql, apollo-client

I created next function in postgres:

```
create or replace FUNCTION public.myFunction(language integer, app_type integer, user uuid, level integer default null, status  integer default null) RETURNS SETOF json
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER
  AS $_$
 begin
    return query 
select json_build_object(
        'rowId', p.id,
        'projectId', p.short_id, 
        'name', p.name,
        'level', pd.level, )
from public.project p join types t on p.type = t.type
join public.project_data pd on pd.project = p.id
where p.language = $1 and ( $5 IS NULL OR p.status = $5) and p.type = 
                            $2 and ( $4 IS NULL OR pd.level = $4) ;
end;
$_$;
```

The goal was to create function that will run with option where parameters. So, if status is passed and level is passed the run with both params. Otherwise, run with status or level if passed or run without those params at all.
However, those clauses does not work `( $4 IS NULL OR pd.level = $4)`, `( $5 IS NULL OR p.status = $5)`

The idea was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048681/556526)

Have to say that status and level are "enum tables".

I found other examples of such postgres function with same approach, but looks like that this approach is not working for me.

My result is always empty nodes

Any suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either try removing the `STRICT` clause, or forbid `NULL` values in the arguments list.